# Usage regarding for loop in solidity contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, contract-debugging, truffle-contract

I am trying to integrate for loop in my smartcontract for adding details to a struct.

I have implemented for loop using frontend by calling the function in smartcontract one by one.

```
 struct details {
    string[] value;
} 
mapping (uint=>details) Details;
function add(uint id,string valuetosubmit){
    Details[id].value=valuetosubmit   
}
```

As I have mentioned,I am calling the function `add` one by one inside a for loop.

I have to move the for loop inside the smart contract.How can it be implemented?
Any samples for reference?
Which is the best method to follow? What will be difference in Gas Consumption?

Comment: Do you really need the dynamically-sized `string` type? This would be much easier if you expose some sort of limit on the string length, for example 32 characters. Then you could use a `bytes32[]` in your new function.

Comment: @JesseBusman I have to use dynamic string...